# PHP Convert UTF-8 to Windows-1252 CSV

Tags: php, csv, encoding, utf-8

I have UTF-8 source data and I must to create CSV file which encoded in Windows-1252 character encoding.

I was tried with classic functions, but I haven't well results. It must support Serbian Characters: "čćžšđ" after converting.

Also I was tried to convert to CP1252, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2 with functions: mb_convert_encoding, iconv and iconv_set_encoding.

Have anyone any idea what to try?

Comment: Note that all text encodings except UTF ones are notoriously unreliable, because there exists no system or standard to indicate which encoding a file is saved in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows-1252 does not contain Serbian letters, try [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) instead.

Both `mb_convert_encoding()` and `iconv()` should work.

Comment: @Daniel Dulić If this answered your question, please consider marking it as solution. ty!